Could not open cp_settings generic class cache for settings file
I Uninstalled Android Studio and then I ReInstalled And I am Trying To Generate SHA1 Key Using This Command In Terminal "./gradlew signingReport" but I am Facing an Exception of Build Failed Caused By Could not open cp_settings generic class cache
I Uninstalled Android Studio and then I ReInstalled And I am Trying To Generate SHA1 Key Using This Command In Terminal "./gradlew signingReport" but I am Facing an Exception of Build Failed Caused By Could not open cp_settings generic class cache.

"Can You Please Never Do This Again"
